# Use KeyTool to turn *.pfx alias into a variable

Tags: powershell, variables, keytool

I feel like I'm probably overthinking this, but I'm running this in Powershell:

```
keytool -list -keystore $pfxName -storepass $pfxPwd
```

When the password is correct, I get:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

te-5668b227-51e2-43ce-ad3a-ea4b4435a247, Apr 18, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 40:87:17:85:84:BC:7D:EB:38:7A:E2:45:36:3E:E9:7B:32:E7:13:95
```

When the password is incorrect I get:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the output into a variable so I can 1) scrape out the alias by itself to run additional commands and 2) verify the password and run a loop if need be until the password is correct.  I know how to do all that if I can turn the output into a variable, but I'm struggling.  Normally I would add:

```
-outvariable output
```

at the end of my line, but that doesn't seem to work with keytool.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
$pfxKeyTool = "keytool -list -keystore $pfxName -storepass $pfxPwd"
$pfxOut = CMD.exe /c $pfxKeyTool
If($pfxOut -eq "keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect"){
#Do Something
}
Else{
#Do Something else
}
```